# list<class>.Select throws System.FormatException exception

Tags: c#, asp.net

the code throws (System.FormatException: Input string was not in a correct format.) excption, what's the problem ?

**designer class**

```
public class designer
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string category { get; set; }
}
```

**getData.aspx Page**

```
List<designer> lst = DataAccess.GetDesigners();
return String.Join(",", lst.Select(x => String.Format("{ label: \"{0}\", category: \"{1}\" }", x.name, x.category)));
```

I need to return code the data like this

```
 [
            { label: "anders", category: "People" },
            { label: "andreas", category: "People" },
            { label: "antal", category: "People" }
          ]
```

Comment: Does `DataAccess.GetDesigners` return `null`?

Comment: I added the exception details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you are using `{` in format string, so to escape `{` it should be followed by `{` and `}` should be followed by `}`

```
lst.Select(x => String.Format("{{ label: \"{0}\", category: \"{1}\" }}", x.name, x.category));
```

**Remember**: Brackets `{}` should be escaped while using `string.Format`

Comment: +1. I did not know you could escape the brackets this way. The documentation does not mention it at all. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like

```
var lst = DataAccess.GetDesigners().Where(x => x != null);
```

protects you from this exception